# Building qt lua on windows

Tags: qt, compilation, lua

While building qtlua i get this error:

```
libqtlua-1.4\src\qtluastate.cc: In member function 'void QtLua::State::gc_collect()':

libqtlua-1.4\src\qtluastate.cc:665:29: error: 'lua_setgcthreshold' was not declared in this scope

mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/qtlua.dir/src/qtluastate.cc.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/qtlua.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any idea how to solve?